# PHP минимальное значение

Tags: php

Есть строка вида `ID1==Vasya==200==URL1|ID2==Petya==100==URL2|ID3==Sergey==300==URL3|` и т.д. Это только пример, цифры, имена и URL могут быть разными. Как правильно найти все данные между `"|"` которые содержат минимальное число? В нашем примере `100,ID2,Petya,URL2`

Начал так:

```
$arr=explode("|", $BDuser);

foreach($arr as $k){

@list($id, $name, $digit, $url) = explode('==',$k);

If(){

   что дальше?

}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кажется, так:

```php
<?php

$arr = explode("|", "ID1==Vasya==200==URL1|ID2==Petya==100==URL2|ID3==Sergey==300==URL3");

$min = PHP_INT_MAX;
$res = 0;

foreach($arr as $k){
    $els = explode("=", $k);
    if ($els[4] < $min){
        $res = $els[4].",".$els[0].",".$els[2].",".$els[6];
        $min = $els[4];
    }
}

echo $res;
```

Вывод:

```
100,ID2,Petya,URL2
```

[Посмотреть в работе.](https://3v4l.org/hf6vd)